# Autoconf: check struct member type

Tags: linux-kernel, autoconf

I am new to **autoconf** so I would ask you how could I check if a *struct member* is declared with a particular type.

For example I should check if **struct posix_acl.a_refcount** is declared as **refcount_t** and not **atomic_t**.

I know AC functions as *ac_fn_c_check_decl* and *ac_fn_c_check_member*, but none that accomplish this task.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: As there are no other answers at the time this answer is being written, this represents my best attempt to provide a solution, but you may need to adjust things to make it work for you.  Caveat emptor.*

You would need to use the `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` macro with code that uses `atomic_t`, and if the compilation succeeds, then you're using `atomic_t`.  As future-proofing, you might also add a test for `refcount_t` if the `atomic_t` test fails.

Example:

```
# _POSIX_ACL_REFCOUNT_T(type-to-check)
# ------------------------------------
# Checks whether the Linux kernel's `struct posix_acl'
# type uses `type-to-check' for its `a_refcount' member.
# Sets the shell variable `posix_acl_refcount_type' to
# `type-to-check' if that type is used, else the shell
# variable remains unset.
m4_define([_POSIX_ACL_REFCOUNT_T], [
 AC_REQUIRE([AC_PROG_CC])
 AC_MSG_CHECKING([whether struct posix_acl uses $1 for refcounts])
 AC_COMPILE_IFELSE(
  [AC_LANG_SOURCE(
   [#include <uapi/../linux/posix_acl.h>
    struct posix_acl acl;
    $1 v = acl.a_refcount;]
  )],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
   AS_VAR_SET([posix_acl_refcount_type], [$1])],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
 )
])

_POSIX_ACL_REFCOUNT_T([atomic_t])
# If posix_acl_refcount_type isn't set, see if it works with refcount_t.
AS_VAR_SET_IF([posix_acl_refcount_type],
    [],
    [_POSIX_ACL_REFCOUNT_T([refcount_t])]
)
dnl
dnl Add future AS_VAR_SET_IF tests as shown above for the refcount type
dnl before the AS_VAR_SET_IF below, if necessary.
dnl
AS_VAR_SET_IF([posix_acl_refcount_type],
    [],
    [AC_MSG_FAILURE([struct posix_acl uses an unrecognized type for refcounts])]
)
AC_DEFINE([POSIX_ACL_REFCOUNT_T], [$posix_acl_refcount_type],
    [The type used for the a_refcount member of the Linux kernel's posix_acl struct.])
```

The tests assume that you already have a variable containing the kernel source directory, and the kernel source's `include` directory is specified in `CPPFLAGS` or `CFLAGS` prior to attempting the tests. You can add more tests at the position indicated, and if the resulting `posix_acl_refcount_type` shell variable is still not defined after all those tests, then the final `AS_VAR_SET_IF` invocation will invoke `AC_MSG_FAILURE` to stop `configure` with the specified error message.

Note that I used `<uapi/../linux/posix_acl.h>` to specifically target the kernel's `linux/posix_acl.h` header rather than the userspace API `uapi/linux/posix_acl.h` header installed in a system's include directory with the `uapi/` stripped off, which may result in the compile tests above failing due to the missing `struct posix_acl` in the userspace API.  This may not work the way I'd expect and may need modification.